# set tab order from one view controls to another view controls in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two views in mvc project.In first view i have three controls.In second view I have four controls.the two views are loaded in same page.If I execute the project the tab index working in first view only.After the tabbed in the First view's three controls.then tab not move to second view control

How to set Tab index for first view to second view controls?

Comment: For the browser it does not matter that parts of html came from different partial views. Examine, and/or include in you question, resulting page html to understand why tabbing between controls (btw, what are these controls?) does not work .

Comment: Can you explain me What are you trying to achieve. May be I can provide you a better approach.